# Making a div responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to get a make a div which contains a set of tools responsive.I have a side menu below this which I have made responsive. Could someone let me know where would this be wrong.

```css
#tools {
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #tools {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tools" style="width: 100%">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Type To Filter" ng-model="search" class="searchMenu">
      </td>
      <td id=uploadedit>
        <button id="upload" onclick="insertIntoDatabase()" class="pinColor"><i class="fa fa-upload fa-2"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td id=impledit>
        <button id="implview" onclick="openImplView()" class="pinColor"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id="home" class="homeButton"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id="keep-menu-open" class="pinColor" ng-click="openAndFixMenu"><i class="pinColor"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id="open-left" class="toggleButton" ng-click="toggleMenu()"> <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: This is the div when the browser is maximized]

[image: The second image is the div after changing the browser size]

Comment: Maybe get rid of your extra # first in your @media query so you actually target #tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your media query: it should be `#` instead of `##`. Aside from that, you're declaring `width: 100%` inline which overwrites whatever you've written in a stylesheet, which is why you don't see the result of the query.

Comment: My bad by adding the ##. I did remove one of it and the changes arent responsive yet.

Comment: What about the `width: 100%` which I mention in my answer?

Comment: This actually changes the size of the div on resizing the browser. Guess my idea of resizing the tools was wrong. Even after the div size changes it doesnt resize the tools which are there in it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to take the style="100%" from the div, any inline style like this will over-ride whatever is in the stylesheet.

Also in the media query you have

```
##tools { width: 70%; }
```

change to

```
#tools { width: 70%; }
```